# How do I change the displayed text within a button using pure js?

Tags: javascript

I'm a beginner to coding and was wondering if you guys might help.

I've seen a lot of stuff online about using `innerHTML`, `textContent`, `value` etc. to change the displayed text for a  tag but I can't get it to actually change on-screen.

Note: the `console.log`'s do fire and display the expected text in the console the correct content but the button content doesn't change in the window.

Here's my html:

```
<h1 id="myHeading" class="red">JavaScript and the DOM</h1>
<p>Making a web page interactive</p>
<button id="myButton">click me</button>
```

Here's my Javascript:

```
const myHeading = document.getElementById('myHeading');
const myButton = document.getElementById('myButton');
let buttonText = myButton.innerText;
console.log(buttonText);

myButton.addEventListener('click', function toggleColor() {
  let whatClass = myHeading.classList;


  if (whatClass.contains('red')) {
    whatClass.remove('red');
    whatClass.add('yellow');
    buttonText = 'Click me to change text to Red!';
    console.log(buttonText);
  } else if (whatClass.contains('yellow')) {
    whatClass.remove('yellow');
    whatClass.add('red');
    buttonText = 'Click me to change text to Yellow!';
    console.log(buttonText);
  }
});
```

Thanks in advance and please don't be too harsh!

Comment: Are you explicitly setting the `innerHTML` property of `myButton` when you set `buttonText`?

Comment: `myButton.innerText` will not give you a reference to the value so can update via it. Use `myButton.innerHTML = "New button text";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `myButton.innerText` or `myButton.innerHTML`

```js
const myHeading = document.getElementById('myHeading');
const myButton = document.getElementById('myButton');
let buttonText = myButton.innerText;
//console.log(buttonText);

myButton.addEventListener('click', function toggleColor() {
  let whatClass = myHeading.classList;


  if(whatClass.contains('red')) {
    whatClass.remove('red');
    whatClass.add('yellow');
    myButton.innerText = 'Click me to change text to Red!';
  
  }
  else if(whatClass.contains('yellow')) {
    whatClass.remove('yellow');
    whatClass.add('red');
    myButton.innerHTML = 'Click me to change text to Yellow!';
   
  }
});
```

```css
.red{background:red}
.yellow{background:yellow}
```

```html
<h1 id="myHeading" class="red">JavaScript and the DOM</h1>
<p>Making a web page interactive</p>
<button id="myButton">click me</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to actually set the text. :-)

```
myButton.innerHTML = buttonText;
```

Oops, I had jQuery in my head!

Comment: `innerHTML` is not a function

Comment: Yeah, I've been using jQuery too much lately...got it mixed up. :-S